# Instead of customer name, how can I show url of customer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[api request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlWyR.png)

In the owner field there is customer name (**changja88**).

Instead of customer name, how can I show url of customer?
Thank you !

Comment: how is the url of customer defined in your code? share your models and views by editing your Q!

Comment: In addition also add the serializer you are using. Also, please avoid using images when posting a question. Use text wherever possible.

Comment: I think you need [`HyperlinkedRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `SerializerMethodField` in your serializer.

```
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    field_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Model

    def get_field_name(self, obj):
        return obj.field_or_method_name
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Comment: Why are you giving a vague answer? First try to understand what code he has written and then a give a suitable answer.